# JQuery not working with asp.net validation control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

All my pages work well with the jquery menu and jquery ui date picker plugins. But the problem is with the page having asp.net validation control. Those pages keep on displaying the error of the type:

> $('mySelector').myFunction(); is not a function

I am working with asp.net 4.5 website with jquery UI 1.7.3 and [jquery dropdown menu with google style](http://www.jqueryload.com/jquery-dropdown-menu-with-google-style).

If I just remove the validation controls in the page it starts working. But I need them.

Any suggestion please? Thanks.

**Updated**
Here is the error as seen in the firebug.

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$("[id$=txtDate1]").datepicker();

AddCon...atid=29 (line 248)
TypeError: $(...).fixedMenu is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$('div.menu').fixedMenu();
```

Comment: I've the same problem, i think is a conflict between the script reference in the page and de jquery referenced by ScriptManager, necessary for Unobtrusive Validation Mode = webform
Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable reason can be $ is conflicting with Asp.net Jquery object.

What you can do is try to declare your separate Jquery object at start of code on page

Try: jquery.NoConflict()

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Could you elaborate "declare your separate Jquery object at start of code on page" please?

Comment: With $.noConflict(); , now jquery menu and jquery date picker work as usual but the validation controls lose the client side behavior.  Non-validated form just posts back which I catch in !Page.isValid section. Any idea please?